# Git Bash Error: Could not fork child process: Permission denied (-1)

Tags: windows, bash, git, azure, active-directory

I have Git for Windows installed by Chocolatey using `choco install git`.
It has been working perfectly for many moons.

A couple of days ago when I opened Git Bash, the window appears with the following:

Title Bar: `/usr/bin/bash --login -i`

Window content: `Error: Could not fork child process: Permission denied (-1)`

[image: Git Bash error]

My colleague is also receiving the *same error message* on his machine. We are using enterprise company laptops joined to a Windows domain. The IT team who support these laptops don't know a lot about Git as most of the organisation is using TFS, so they are not sure how to support this. Is it likely a Group Policy update or similar might have caused this? The organisation is also moving towards SSO (I think through Azure AD) - could this be related?

I have tried the following:

- Update git to the latest v2.16.1.2
- This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45803951/335366
- Reboot windows
- Run Git Bash as Administrator
- Run Git Bash using the Explorer Context menu: "Git Bash Here"

Nothing works. How can I resolve this either locally or through the domain / active directory / group policy?

Git GUI seems to work on my colleague's machine but is not working on mine. When I load Git GUI I get error:

[image: Git GUI error Message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to this.

In my case, the issue was being caused by a new policy in **McAfee Endpoint Security.**

To resolve, my IT Support admin created a new Allow policy for the Git executables. I updated McAfee with **Check/Enforce policies** in the **McAfee Agent Status Monitor**. Following that, I had to reinstall Git due to some read-only permission issue. Problem solved. The solution may differ for other organisations but the main point is that if you encounter this issue suddenly in an Enterprise network,  look to your endpoint security solution policies first as the most probable cause of the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:

Close the Git Bash window.
Open Task manager.
Find the 'bash.exe' process.
Kill it.
Open Git Bash.